# How to Fix TypeError Model is not a Constructor?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to replicate this [push notification project](https://felixgerschau.com/web-push-notifications-tutorial/#project-setup) written in TS but using javascript.

This are following function:

```
Subscription Model:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const SubscriptionModel = new Schema({
    endpoint: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    expirationTime: { type: Number, required: false },
    keys: {
        auth: String,
        p256dh: String,
    },
});
        
const model = mongoose.model('Subscription', SubscriptionModel);

module.export = model
```

SubscriptionRepository

```
const Subscription =  require('../model/SubscriptionModel')

const create = async (subscription) => {
    try{
        const newSubscription = new Subscription.model(subscription);        
        const savedSubscription = await newSubscription.save();
        return savedSubscription.toObject();
    }catch(err){
        return err
    }
};

module.exports = {create:create}
```

Route Subscription

```
app.post("/subscription", async (req, res) => {
  try{
    (async() => {
      const subscription = req.body;
      const newSubscription = subscriptionRepository.create(subscription);
      console.log(newSubscription);
      res.status(201).json(newSubscription)
    })();        
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }

});
```

Error:

> Promise {
> TypeError: Subscription.model is not a constructor }

This is my first time using Moongose I dont have idea even searching how to fix! Any suggestion to help me?

Sub Object:

```
{ endpoint:
   'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dYGGHvDYLtk:APA91bHIkbLj-Fi0VKrhRuemQZiwc1G49bls0obRGlyPJ6MLisgm3s_lGLvts9jKUaAHKWxxMFlw7imLY8YqEU1C83YNRREdZ70nnVamFFLSANWpZ922z-tysSQhEjBquhISE9rv2RtK',
  expirationTime: null,
  keys:
   { p256dh:
      'BOVN3GYiheBK77iPxZecbagZCMXLi06YE8pe-O-dKSmd8r_ccObMYyJ8oYbIQw7htNSxIv4mP5awABRq0LskE6I',
     auth: '8x9bTem324oY4-P9jKcuSQ' } }
```

Error output:

```
Promise {
  TypeError: Subscription.model is not a constructor
      at Object.create (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/controller/subscriptionRepository.js:5:33)
      at /home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/server.js:31:54
      at app.post (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/server.js:34:7)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at next (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
      at Route.dispatch (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at /home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
      at Function.process_params (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
      at next (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
      at serveStatic (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at trim_prefix (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
      at /home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
      at Function.process_params (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
      at next (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) }
```

Comment: Did you try `const newSubscription = new Subscription(subscription)` ?

Comment: Just tried! Some error ` TypeError: Subscription.model is not a constructor `

Comment: output to console the whole `Subscription` object and add this output to your post

Comment: updated question

Comment: It looks like a record object and not a model itself. Show output of `model` before `module.export = model`

Comment: sorry, do you want to show you Schema output or the const model in `SubscriptionModel`

Comment: show `const model`, please

Comment: Output const Model = `Model { Subscription }`